# First call to WCF is slow (20 to 30 Seconds)

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, iis, xmlserializer

We have a WCF Service hosted in IIS 7.5 and whilst working on this particular WCF Service (more than 600 operation contracts) we notice that after restarting the IIS/Application pool; first call to WCF's method takes more than 20-30 seconds to complete.

However, subsequent calls to WCF get processed quickly (in milliseconds). We would like minimise this time as it will have an impact on the user experience of the first user.

We have also noticed that if we reduce the number of operation contracts to 5/10 then time it takes to complete the first call reduces dramatically (in milliseconds).

WCF Client proxy has been generated through the svcutil.exe utility. We have made the following changes to see if we can fix this behavior, however, we are 
still encountering the same time frames to complete the first call.

1. Disabled/Remove publishing of MataData Binding
2. Default web proxy has been disabled.
3. We have implemented the Auto-Start feature of the IIS and implemented the “Preload” method of the IProcessHostPreloadClient interface and
   Called “ System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailable(virtualPath)” method.
4. IIS > Idle Timeout = 0 (Never Timeout).
5. We have SGEN-ed all the DLLS we have on Server, still no breakthrough.
6. Took memory dumps to see if DLL.XmlSerializers.dll file is loaded in the memory.
7. Executed ProcMon & ProcExp to see if targeted files are loaded in the memory.

I have read 1000s to pages suggesting (Auto-Start feature, SGENing, PreLoad implementation etc.), however, we have not got a solution to reduce the time frame it takes to complete the first call to WCF.

### Development Environment

IIS 7.5
.Net Framework 4.6
Windows 7 - 64 Bit
Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you included in IProcessHostPreloadClient  method? Is it opening the proxy or not? What was the result of memory dumps, is it using the Serializer dll? Is it a .net WCF Client?

Comment: 1- Nothing major, We have some code to write a simple Text file to save some logs i.e. what are we doing. I can confirm that PreRoad method gets called and logs get saved in the target text file. 

2- No, it does not. Memory consumption stays moderate 25K, however, as soon as we initiate the first call memory goes up to 75K.

3- Initially memory dumps indicate that (let's call it mycompany.dll) MyCompany.DLL gets loaded in the Memory and 
pre-generated XMl Serializer verson of MyCompany (myCompany.XmlSerializer.dll) also gets loaded in the memory.
We can confirm this by running verious tools.

Comment: However, other dependencies files (let's say Reference1.dll, Reference2.dll) are not loaded in the memory. 
At this stage we made the following changes:

- Pre-generated xml seriliazer files for other dependencies.
- We have also loaded the dependency files + Pre-generated xml seriliazer files MANUALLY (by using Assembly.Load Method)
  and we could see them loaded in the memory as soon as IIS gets restarted OR Application pool gets started.

4- Yes, we are using WinForms Application to connect with WCf Services hosted on IIS Server (Load Balanced).

Comment: One of the other idea we had was to call WCF Service within the PreLoad method so it starts loading underlying DLLs in the memory. However, this won't be an appropriate solution because we have multiple WorkProcesses defined against the Application Pool, which means although the first Worker Process will start loading the DLLs but when IIS spins up the 2nd instance of work process and call the WCF service then request will be sent to 1st instance of work process (not to the second because 2nd instance is not ready to receive requests). We have 5 Workprocesses set for application pool.

Comment: The **most important thing** is that you need to do these things at ***WinForms Application*** which is the client and not at the WCF Service. Have you done this at Service side or Client side? Reading from comments, it seems you have used XML Serializer dll's at Server and not at client side.

Comment: I have done same things at Client too (apart from Preload that can be done on Server Side) and still no avail. I would stress the fact that client channel initialization/Security negotiation etc. does take almost 4 to 5 seconds, however, loading the DLLs on server side takes more than 25 seconds. Therefore, my aim is to reduce the time as Server end (not client end). WCF tracing clearly indicates that it takes time towards the server (not client).

Comment: "FromMappings"  this is a method gets called during a JIT-ing process. If you check the source of this method on REferenceSource.Microsoft.com then you will see that it will first check if pre-generated XMLSerializer file exists on the machine. If it does then it will further check the Version + Namespace check and in my case this is what fails and causing the generation of on-the-fly XMl file generation. This on the fly generation takes majority of time and fixing this area would certainly help to reduce the time frame it takes to complete first call.

Comment: For your reference I am adding the link where you can check the source code.  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs,3c39909586c83e11